# SAPUI5 IconTab with separate controllers handle lazy-loading

Tags: sapui5

This question is regarding Lazy-Loading. I read the Help portal, but that is for "one-controller-case". It is stated there, that Lazy loading should be implemented when:

> In real use cases, you would do this for tabs that contain a lot of content or trigger expensive service calls to a back-end service.

But it's not mentioned how then to trigger controllers RouteMatched event, because `.getTargets().display("name")` doesn't trigger the event.

Asking this because Parent's local view JSON Model has data, that was gathered in Parent's Controllers _onObjectMatched function, namely `this.sObjId= oEvent.getParameter("arguments").objectId;`
the same information I need in nested controllers - to send GET request with these parameters when Tab is clicked.

Also workaround to get properties from Parent's ViewModel would be fine.

I do not want to use .navTo function onTabSelect event - cause that triggers Route matched every Time - so if I switch between tabs - multiple same GET are sent.

Explanation on how should IconTabFilter work with separate controller is highly appreciated!

Thanks, Shanir

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but: I couldn't get this solved with routing either and attachDisplay didn't help as it had no context information.
So I used the EventBus and that worked:

In your detail controllers bind method:

```
this.getView().bindElement({
  path: ...,
  events: {
    dataReceived: function () {
     sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerComponentFor(that.getView()).getEventBus().publish(
                            "BindingDone", {
                                oContext: that.getView().getBindingContext()
                            }
                        );
                    }
```

And then in your controller for the IconTabBar content:

```
onInit: function () {
            var oEventBus = sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerComponentFor(this.getView()).getEventBus();
            oEventBus.subscribe(
                "BindingDone",
                this.onBinding,
                this
            );
        },
```

and

```
onBinding: function (sChannelId, sEventId, oData) {
            this.getView().setBindingContext(oData.oContext);
        }
```

It bypasses the whole routing mechanism so if anyone has a better solution please correct me.

Best,
Marcus